# Dos modales en la misma pagina no abre uno de ellos

Tags: html, modal

tengo dos modales en una misma pagina, mi problema es que uno de ellos no abre quando hago click en el boton. lo que ocurre es que el modal 2 no abre cuando los tendo en la secuencia modal1 y modal2, pero cuando cabio de posicion el modal2 e modal1 el modal1 no abre.

Alguen puede ayudarme? ya he intentado de todo pero no encuentro el problema.

```
<div class="row">
        <a type="button 2"class="dropdown-item"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1" href="#">modal 1</a>

        <a type="button 2" class="dropdown-item"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal2" href="#">modal 2</a>
```

```
  <!--MODAL1-->

  <div id="modal1" class="modal fade "  >
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg"  >
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-body" style="font-size: 12px;">
          <div class="modal-header" style="color: #545454;">
            <h5 class="modal-title"><i class="fas fa-money"></i> Modal 1</h5>
          </div>





        </div><!--/modal-body-->

      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->


<!--FIM MODAL1-->
```

```
  <div id="modal2" class="modal fade ">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" style="color: #545454;">
            <h5 class="modal-title"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Modal 1</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="font-size: 12px;">





         </div><!--/modal-body-->

    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

```
<!--FIM MODAL2-->
```

Comment: No podemos solucionar tu código sin siquiera verlo. Por favor súbelo y podremos ayudarte encontrando el error. Seguramente ya te han recomendado leer [ask], por favor léelo y no lo omitas.

Comment: @ Víctor Hugo Tirado. No he conseguido poner todo el código.

Comment: Puedes usar algunas herramientas como [https://gist.github.com/]

Comment: @Rodrigo Arenas González. No entendi lo que quieres decir. En el link que indicas no aparece nada.

Comment: Para que puedas colocar todo el código, y podamos darte un mejor soporte para el problema que tienes